# C# MVC4 Razor - style disabled checkboxes with CSS or

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have some `bool` values in my model and

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.myBool)
```

displays my checkbox in my *index/delete.cshtml* without having to care that it's a checkbox or something else - that's nice, but ...

The checkbox is displayed disabled - that's ok in terms of having them *readonly*, but the style of disabled checkboxes is too lightgrey and the readability isn't perfect.

So what would you suggest?

My preferred way would be some CSS, but something like

```
input[type=checkbox]:disabled { "inherit the style of enabled checkboxes" }
```

isn't possible in CSS (to my knowledge) and

```
input[type=checkbox]:disabled { ... }
```

doesn't seem to have any effect. Firebug shows that the syntax is right and the code should be used, but whatever I write in there, e.g. `background-color: red` is ignored (at least in Firefox, didn't test on other browsers).

Other possible solutions: having images - seems very ugly to me, CSS is the way for styling (at least it should be).

So far, my workaround is using

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.myBool)
```

and prevent clicks on it by adding a jquery/javascript (you may want to adapt the selector in case you have checkboxes in your View that you want to use for more than displaying purposes)

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () { return false; });
```

It displays the checkboxes as I want them, but I'd prefer some direct way using some options in the `@Html.Display(...)` or using CSS instead of Javascript.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Tried it in some of my projects, not working accordingly is should... Recommend a plug-in or not doing this ..

Comment: @JelleOosterbosch What was not working? CSS? My workaround above? Something else? Which plug-in would you recommend?

Comment: My css ways where not working. The fastest & most easy way is to catch the return statement as your workaround supposes...